# Rails JSON API: add top level element to get by id API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a JSON API that returns a collection of objects, API is using `to_json` and `ActiveModel::Serializer` to generate the JSON. I get JSON with structure that looks like this:

```
{
  "objects": [ 
               { "id": 1, "key1": 2 }, { "id": 2, "key2": 3 } 
             ]
}
```

I want to keep the same structure for "get by id" API that returns single object. Currently get by id returns following JSON structure:

```
{ "id": 1, "key1": 2 }
```

Is there a way to wrap the JSON for get by id API in root element? I want JSON structure to look like this:

```
{
  "objects":  { "id": 1, "key1": 2 }
}
```

Comment: post you code which is dealing with serving json

Comment: How are you generating the json?  `to_json`, jbuilder, rabl, a custom ruby template handler, etc?

Comment: @steakchaser: `to_json`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared much about your implementation details, but I would suggest looking into the `jbuilder` GEM. It provides a bit more flexibility with API design than what you typically get "out of the box" with Rails:

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder